# Bogomolov–Miyaoka–Yau inequality for minimal varieties with intermediate Kodaira dimension $0<\kappa (X)<\dim X$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, stability, minimal-model-program

From the differential geometric proof of Yau and the algebraic proof of Miyaoka for minimal varieties of general type $\kappa (X)=\dim X$, we know that $$(-1)^nc_1^n(X)\leq (-1)^n\frac{2(n+1)}{n}  c_1^{n-2}(X)c_2(X)$$

> What can we say about the Bogomolov–Miyaoka–Yau inequality for minimal
>    varieties with an intermediate Kodaira dimension  $0<\kappa(X)<\dim
>  X$?
>
> So I guess we need to prove the following inequality:
>
> $$\left(\frac{2(n+1)}{n}c_2(\mathcal T_{X/X_{can}})-c_1^2(\mathcal
>  T_{X/X_{can}})\right).[\omega]^{n-2}\geq 0$$
>
> where $\omega$ is a Kahler form on the minimal projective variety
>   $X=X_{min}$ and $X_{can}=\text{Proj}\bigoplus_{m\geq 0}H^0(X,K_X^{m})$
>   is the canonical model of $X$ (here  $\mathcal T_{X/X_{can} 
> }=Hom(Ω^1_{X/X_{can}}, \mathcal O_X)$ mean relative tangent sheaf) via
>   Iitaka fibration $\pi: X\to X_{can}$.

Certainly we must require stability in order that this inequality holds true. The stability must be equivalent with the fact that the following flow converges in $C^\infty$$$\frac{\partial\omega(t)}{\partial t}=-Ric_{X/X_{can}}(\omega(t))-\omega(t)$$

Here $Ric_{X/X_{can}}=dd^c\log \Omega_{X/X_{can}}$(where $\Omega_{X/X_{can}}$ is the relative volume form) means relative Ricci form. Note that if such relative Kahler Ricci flow has solution then $K_{X/X_{can}}$ is psudo-effective
I think that the analytical minimal model program can prove this.

In fact I guess if we have relative Kahler-Einstein metric $Ric_{X/X_{can}}\omega=-\omega$ ,  then Bogomolov–Miyaoka–Yau inequality for minimal varieties with intermediate Kodaira dimension $0<\kappa (X)<\dim X$ holds true.

Comment: You can have a look at the following paper for instance: https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.05981

Comment: See the following paper for logarithmic version  ;)  H. Tsuji, Stability of tangent bundles of minimal algebraic varieties, Topology, 27, no. 4
(1988), 429-442 . The question for positive Kodaira dimension is still open

Comment: @Henri , if you apply the method of the following paper for conical Kahler Ricci flow you can get much simpler proof http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2009-137-08/S0002-9939-09-09838-4/S0002-9939-09-09838-4.pdf

Comment: You need to assume that $X$ is minimal, otherwise even the original MY inequality is false

Comment: And for your proposed inequality in the case of intermediate Kodaira dimension, you probably need to assume that $K_X$ is semiample, otherwise the Iitaka fibration won't be a morphism.

Comment: What is $Ric_{X/X_{can}}$?

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. $K_{X/X_{cam}}$ is a line bundle, so only $c_1$ makes sense and $c_2$ vanishes.

Comment: In fact MY inequality is known for minimal varieties of general type i.e $\kappa (X)=\dim X$,  but for minimal varieties with an intermidiate Kodaira dimension i.e. $0<\kappa (X)<\dim X$, there bust be such MY type inequality correspond to relative tangent sheaf of minimal variety and its canonical model, but we need to require a notion of stability. I changed the notation

Comment: @YangMills , original proof of the paper of Miyaoka had a gap, you was right. I changed the notation

Comment: I still do not understand. I would expect that your conjectural inequality should reduce to the Bogomolov-Miyaoka-Yau for $X$ of general type. However in this case the relative tangent sheaf $\mathcal T_{X/X_{can}}$ is trivial. May be you want $\pi^* T_{X_{can}}$ instead?

Comment: I have assumed $\kappa (X)\neq \dim X$ and fibers are CY here. So for intermidiate Kodaira dimension varieties you think we need to use pull back of tangent sheaf of canonical model instead relative tangent sheaf $\mathcal T_{X/X_{can} 
}$?

Comment: As far as I know , Any stable bundle which admit canonical metric like hermitian Einstein metric, Higg Einstein metric, ...ect, we have such inequality, so for relative Einstein metric on Iitaka fibration we must get such inequality

Comment: see short survey paper of Demailly https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/chern

Comment: @Yury Ustinovskiy, I guess you are confusing about my notation, first chern class of $c_1(TX_s)$ where $X_s$ is Calabi-Yau is zero, but $c_1(T_{X/X_{can}})$ in general is not zero even fibers be Calabi-Yau, and depence to hermitian metric and by choosing fiberwise Calabi-Yau form, such first Chern class of relative tangent sheaf is Weil-Petersson metric for instance. So I think my notation is correct